# Programmatically created button onclick generating illegal value error

Tags: javascript, function, google-sheets, sidebar

In a google scripts sidebar, I have javascript in a html page that creates a button at the bottom of the sidebar. The button generates a "Failed due to illegal value in property: 0" in console when clicked. When the button is hard coded, the same function works. In the developer screen, the hard coded button text and the javascript generated button code appear to be identical.

I have tried several methods of creating the button and placing it at the bottom of the page including moving the location of the function and function call that creates the button in that when the button is created has an effect on functionality.

A simplified example of the html that is used to populate the sidebar.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

   makeButton();

   function makeButton(){
   var buttontext = "Click Me";
   var func = "AddTalent(this.Parentnode)";
   var scriptcall = "google.script.run."+func";
   var outputb2 = "<p 'align=right'>"+ "<input type='button' 
   value='"+buttontext+"' onClick='"+scriptcall+"'>" + "</input>" +"</p>";
   document.getElementById("processButton").innerHTML = outputb2;
   }

</script>
</head>
<body>
....
1 or more Dropdown
1 or more sets of checkboxes
.....
<div id="processButton"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to use javascript to generate a html compliant button in a Google spreadsheet sidebar and that is placed inside a div or span that, when clicked, passes the select options from one or more groups of dropdown boxes and checkboxes to a google script function.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: This part of your code is wrong var scriptcall = "google.script.run."+func";  think the double quotation marks at the end is wrong, right?

Comment: You could also look into Template strings to make the code more readable,

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your code, I would suggest using template strings to make your code more readable. But I don't know if this resolves the error you are getting.

```
function makeButton(){
  var buttontext = "Click Me";
  var func = "AddTalent(this.Parentnode)";
  var scriptcall = `google.script.run.${func}`;

  var outputb2 = `<p 'align=right'><input type='button' 
  value="${buttontext}" onClick="${scriptcall}"></input></p>`;

  document.getElementById("processButton").innerHTML = outputb2;
  }
```